# How can I use chrome.runtime.sendMessage without responseCallback?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

As specified in [chrome.runtime's page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage), responseCallback is an optional parameter for sendMessage. However, it doesn't seem that way because when I code sendMessage like this:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage("hello")
```

I get this error when I click the button where I added sendMessage as an event handler:

> Uncaught Error: Invocation of form runtime.connect(null, ) doesn't match definition runtime.connect(optional string extensionId, optional object connectInfo)

(Note: runtime.connect is not part of my code. I'm guessing sendMessage invokes it.)

But when I code sendMessage like this:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage("hello", function(response) {});
```

There's no error and everything works fine. My extension receives the message. Here's a code snippet from my extension:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log("from a content script: " + sender.tab.url);
    console.log("message: " + message);
});
```

And here's the output displayed in the console:

> from a content script: http://localhost:8000/practice%20page/index.html
>
> message: hello

I'm fine (kind of) with calling sendMessage with an empty function as a 2nd argument to make it work but it just looks so unnecessary and unclean.

Am I missing anything here? Was there an update to chrome's extension API that made responseCallback a required parameter for sendMessage? (and perhaps [developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime) was just not updated to reflect that change?)

Halp!

Comment: The API confuses the string with an optional extension id, apparently. Send your data as an object e.g. {data: 'foo'}

Comment: You're right. Thank you! I'm curious, though, as to why the error message says null when what I passed as an argument is a "hello" string...

Comment: I guess it's because "hello" isn't a vliad extension id so it gets transformed to `null`. Overall this seems like a bug in Chrome.